# How to delete a preexisting text file found in the raw folder by pressing a button?

Tags: android, file, directory

I am trying to design a button that when pressed will delete a pre-existing file called "names.txt" which has a directory (at least based in android studio) of:

app/src/main/res/raw/names.txt.

After looking all over, I have been unable to find the best way to do this.  Any clarity will help!

(I'm happy to provide more details, but I think a more general answer would help direct me towards the proper solution)

Comment: You **can't**. Resource files are untouchable at runtime. You can only *open them for reading*.

Comment: Thank you so much for informing me this Kling Klang 5.  I've been burning through hours trying to identify a solution. Glad to know definitively that there is not.

Andrew B.